# my error object is undefined when i`m using rtk query with try/catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, rtk-query

first of all i want to apologize for my title. I just dont know how to describe my problem.

I am trying to get a bad response from my server and when I try to display that my object is undefined

I have a base query methods here:

```
export const accountSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        login: builder.mutation({
            query: credentials => ({
                url: 'account/login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: { ...credentials },
            })
        }),
        register: builder.mutation({
            query: credentials => ({
                url: 'account/register',
                method: 'POST',
                body: { ...credentials },
            })
        })
    })
})
```

My handle submit on register page ->

```
    const [register, { isLoading, isError }] = useRegisterMutation();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const result = await register({ name, nickName, email, password }).unwrap();
            setRegisterResponse(result);
        } catch (error) {
            setRegisterResponse(error);
        }
    }
```

And my logic to show it. When i use console.log(registerResponse) it returnes two logs in console - first object is empty, second object with properties ->

```
               {
                    isError &&
                    <h2>
                        Ooops.. something went wrong:
                        {
                           console.log(registerRespnse)
                        }
                    </h2>
                }
```

[Error in google console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMFgQ.png)

Comment: If you're getting an error, edit the question to add the error itself and the line it's coming from.

Comment: @AndyRay i have a comment where im getting and error ( // unfedined) but okey, i will add it

Comment: If you are getting an error, please edit your question to add the error message itself, and the line it's coming from. Are you getting an error in the Chrome Javascript console, or just seeing an undefined object? Either way, all you should need to do is `console.log(registerResponse)` to see what the issue is. Get in the habit of using console.log to debug your code.

Comment: @AndyRay I tried to edit my question as you requested. Also i added an image of error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call a `setRegisterResponse` state setter, because that response will just be available for you:

```js
  //                              see data and error here
  const [register, { isLoading, isError, data, error }] = useRegisterMutation();
```

As why it logs `undefined` once: first the query finishes with an error (which will rerender the component and already fill `error` I showed above and set `isError`) and **then** the Promise resolves and your custom code sets your `response` local state, which causes a second rerender (and only on the second render, `response` is set)

Comment: you saved my life. thank you very much
and also thanks for the comment about why it happend